# PHP- cannot show/hide from SQL data using JQuery toggle function -?

Tags: php, sql, jquery-ui, jquery

Consider a table with 3 rows "ID" "Name" "phone-Number".

I am using PHP for connecting the UI with my SQL database.

the thing i want on my UI is ...

full IDs will b displayed on the page...

using **jQuery Toggle function** . When clicking on one of **ID** it should **fetch** information according to its value from data base and show **Name** and **phone-Number** down. Similarly by clicking the **ID** it should hide the content.

I have tried several ways but I am not getting it write. Can anyone help me out with this.

This is my PHP code.

http://snipsave.com/user/profile/karthikeyan#5351

I used **jQuery** for **toggling** but when I click on button it hides all other data and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

remove that `<button id="hide">Hide</button>`
and use...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#show").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var i = $(this).next("i:first");
    i.toggle();
    $(this).text( ( i.is(":visible") ) ? "Hide" : "Show" );
  });
});
```

and i suggest you to use `class` instead of `id`

Comment: well can u get the problem which i have mention above ?